# Unique index (covering 3 columns) is not used in join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a question regarding the (non-)usage of a unique index. I'm using Oracle 11g.

**Table A:** col1, col2, col3. **col1-col2-col3** triplet has a multiple-column unique index in Table A.

**Table B:** colX. **colX** is the primary key of Table B.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.col1 = B.colX
WHERE A.col2 = 10 and A.col3 = 20
```

When I look at the Explain Plan in Toad, I see that "Every row in TABLE_A is read." (Full Access).

However, when I write the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE A.col1 = 10 AND A.col2 = 20 AND A.col3 = 30
```

it uses the Unique Index.

I also tried to use IN, but indexes are not used in IN queries as well. Is there any way to use this unique index in this sort of join query? If not, can you point me another way to increase the speed of this query? Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Column_order Read about `composite index`.

Comment: The unique index definition could help us help you. I would guess that col2 is declared before col3, so the query without col2 is forced into a table scan. If you'll be using Queries like 1 more often, you should consider reordering the index columns.

Comment: If the first column in where matches the first column in index,the index will be used(in general).Create an `index (col2,col3)` if you want an index on your first query.

Comment: [at] ckuhn203: I tried (col1,col2,col3) and (col2,col3,col1) and some other orders, but it still uses table-scan.
@Mihai: index(col2,col3) works. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `TABLE_A`, make one index with `col1` only (to use for the join) and another index with `col2` and `col3` only (to use for the filtering predicate).

The query optimizer will treat the JOIN and the filtering as two separate operations. It will not use an index with `col1` as the first column for the filtering operation.